# How to configure specific location for logs

Tags: java, logging, oracle-adf

I have a standalone program which using ADF. In that, for log messages am using "***oracle.adf.share.logging.ADFLogger***".

When I deploy it to weblogic server as a web application am able to see log files under MY_DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/logs folder.

But when I run this application as standalone program, where can I find the log files written by my application ?
Can I configure custom location for log files ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into logging.xml file at this location 
C:\Users\Sid\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.7.40.64.93\DefaultDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\DefaultServer on your system .

Here you can specify the path where the log file would get generated , your custom log handler and many other things .

-Sid