# How to change the logging level on Weblogic server

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

How can I change the logging level on a weblogic sever.

My code is adding logs the following way :

```
import oracle.adf.share.logging.ADFLogger;

public class MyClass{

private static final ADFLogger logger = ADFLogger.createADFLogger(MyClass.class); 

public void myMethod(){
  logger.info(" A ");
  logger.debug(" B ");
  logger.severe(" C ");
}

}
```

I can see only the sever level logs in my weblogic server logs. None of the debug and info level logs are appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer [Server Log location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961753/how-to-configure-specific-location-for-logs/31972736#31972736) . The location mentioned in the answer is of I-WLS . In this logging.xml file , you can specify the logging level for ODLLogger (Should be finer or Finest for your case). Also check whether the server is running in Production mode or Dev mode.
If File system is not accessible to you, you can also change the level of logging from EM. There are many blogs available on this.

-Sid